# Getting an error using ESRI's Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to display the query results of a button click on a map.

I am getting the following error at this line: **queryTask.execute(cntryq);** of my script:

> TypeError {stack: "TypeError: undefined is not a function↵ at coun…ndler (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/init.js:490:212)", message: "undefined is not a function"}
>
> message: "undefined is not a function"
>   stack: "TypeError: undefined is not a function↵ at countries (http://tobagoborn.com/esri/examples/p1p2c.html:149:15)↵ at cntrycds (http://tobagoborn.com/esri/examples/p1p2c.html:163:5)↵ at http://tobagoborn.com/esri/examples/p1p2c.html:179:7↵ at S._resolve (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/layers/FeatureLayer.js:64:294)↵ at k (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/layers/FeatureLayer.js:65:355)↵ at c (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/init.js:74:221)↵ at d (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/init.js:74:10)↵ at resolve.callback (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/init.js:75:350)↵ at Object.n._resDfd (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/init.js:758:31)↵ at e._successHandler (http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/init.js:490:212)"

---

**MY SCRIPT**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Display Feature layer Query results</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="claro">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="NSM" value="NSM">News</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="SDG" value="SDG">SDG Status</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="CMP" value ="CMP">City Models/Plans</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="CSM" value ="CSM">Story Maps</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="EDU" value ="EDU">Educational Games</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="USR" value ="USR">User Submitted</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="OPM" value ="OPM">Project Map</button>
</div>

<div name="container" id="container">
<div id="mapDiv"></div>
<div id="sidecol"> </div>
</div>

<script>
  var countries;
  var buttonPicked;
  var buttonType;
  var countryCode = [];
  var whrString = ""
  var map, featureLayer, relatedTable;

var featureURL = "http://dev.consciousglobalchange.org/arcgis/rest/services/MEP/webmap_catalog/FeatureServer/0";
var relatedURL = "http://dev.consciousglobalchange.org/arcgis/rest/services/MEP/webmap_catalog/FeatureServer/1";

    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) 
    { 
        map = new Map("mapDiv", 
        {
            center: [-5.049, 38.485],
            zoom: 2,
            basemap: "gray"
        });
    });

function clickType(e) {
  if (!relatedTable) 
  {
    // The related table hasn't loaded properly yet. Abort!
    alert("Still waiting to connect to the related table.");
    return;
  }

  // "this" refers to the button that was clicked, since this is function added to onClick.
  // "value" reads the "value" attribute from the button.

  var type = this.value;
  require([ //"esri/tasks/query"
  "esri/map", 
  "esri/tasks/query", 
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "esri/tasks/RelationshipQuery",
  "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(FeatureLayer,Query,QueryTask,on, RelationshipQuery)
  {
    var q = new Query();  //RESULTS OF BUTTON CLICK QUERRY PASSED TO relatedTable.queryFeatures fuction 
        q.outFields = ["*"]; 
        q.where = "TYPE = '" + type + "'";
        q.outFields = ["un_country"];

        function countries(uncode) //DISPLAYS RESULTS OF QUERY FOR COUNTRIES
        {
            //build query task
            alert( 'country codes: ' + uncode);
            var queryTask = new QueryTask(featureURL);
            //build query filter
            var cntryq = new Query();
            cntryq.returnGeometry = true;
            cntryq.outFields = ["*"];
            cntryq.where =  "UN in (" + uncode + ")";

            //Can listen for onComplete event to process results or 
            //can use the callback option in the queryTask.execute method.
            dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function(featureSet) 
            {
                map.graphics.clear();
                var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
                new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
                new dojo.Color([255,255,255,0.35]), 1),new dojo.Color([125,125,125,0.35]));

                //QueryTask returns a featureSet.  Loop through features 
                //in the featureSet and add them to the map.
                var data = featureSet.features; 
                console.log(data);

                dojo.forEach(data,function(feature){
                    var graphic = feature;
                    graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
                    map.graphics.add(graphic);
                });
            });
            **queryTask.execute(cntryq);**
        } //end of Countries


        function cntrycds(allcds)  //CREATES A STRING PASSED TO countries function
        {                          
            //alert(allcds);
            whrString = ""
            for (var i = 0; i < allcds.length; i++) 
            {
                //alert(allcds[i]);
                whrString += allcds[i] + ", ";
            }
            whrString = whrString.slice(0, -2);  
            countries(whrString);
            //alert(allcds);
        }

            relatedTable.queryFeatures(q, function(featureSet) 
            {
                countryCode = [];
                //console.log(featureSet.features);
                var data = featureSet.features; 
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                {
                    countryCode[i] = data[i].attributes.un_country;
                    //console.log(data[i].attributes.un_country);
                    //alert(countryCode[i]);
                }

                cntrycds(countryCode);
            });
  });  //end of require 
} //end clickType

require([
  "esri/map", 
  "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", 
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "esri/tasks/RelationshipQuery",
  "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer,Query,QueryTask,on, RelationshipQuery)  
  { 
        var table = new FeatureLayer(relatedURL, 
        {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });

        table.on("load", function (e) 
        {
            relatedTable = e.layer;
        });

    }); //end require



$('#NSM').click(clickType); 
$('#SDG').click(clickType); 
$('#CMP').click(clickType); 
$('#CSM').click(clickType);
$('#EDU').click(clickType);
$('#USR').click(clickType);
$('#OPM').click(clickType);
</script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: I am a newbie when it comes to esri's js-api.  I am actually combining 2 scripts. The first part (uses a Query) I figured out how to return the country codes from a table when you click a button.  The 2nd part (uses a QueryTask) I figured out how to display the countries based on an array of county codes.  Now I need to combine them.  I plan to review the code once I get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the order of dependencies in your require statement match the order of the corresponding variable names. For example, the correct order for the second require should be
`require([
  "esri/map", 
  "esri/tasks/query", 
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "dojo/on",
  "esri/tasks/RelationshipQuery",
  "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(Map, Query, FeatureLayer, QueryTask, on, RelationshipQuery)`

Comment: Thanks ashima, I reviewed my require method and made the necessary changes.  I am still getting the same error

Comment: Hmm. Did you also fix the third require? Because when I run it, I don't get any error.

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle for it - http://jsfiddle.net/798wbh4b/

Comment: Thanks Ashima for the jsfiddle!! Found the cause of the error... The 2nd require dependencies were out of order...

Comment: @ashima Despite having the correct order, I get "Uncaught Reference: Geometry Service is not defined" error! How to get the ordering between dojo/esri js right?

Answer (score 2):

For starters this isn't valid Html:

```
**queryTask.execute(cntryq);**
```

I removed the ** symbols from line and the code ran fine. If you want to comment something out in code, use the `//` symbol in javascript.

Part 2:

Used the Chrome Developer console to find the problem. Some of your buttons at the top pass a *null*  into your CountryCode method. The javascript then attempts to execute `queryTask.execute(Null);` which blows the queryTask up since there is nothing to possibly perform a query on. You'll need to check for null and not call that line if the county code is null.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I used the ** to try to bold the code so you can find it.  I don't want to comment it out... That is the piece of code that is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the null issue.. It's also blowing up for the the ones that are not Null.

Comment: Because your recursive searching eventually ends in a null.

Comment: ChargerllC... Are you saying for example the first button returns a code of 332 as well as an null? If yes, how were able to "see" that it is returning a null also?

Comment: Anytime you see 'undefined' in your error, that's letting you know that an null(also called undefined in javascript) occurred. Using Chrom dev console, I put a break point on the line throwing the error. If there is no related Country Code, your javascript is still executing, putting a null in since no country code was actually found.

Comment: This link describes what I did:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Ok. I am totally lost.  I did as ChargerllC recommended and used Chrome dev console and added a null/undefine check.  If you click on the News button there is no null/undefined variable being passed.  If I comment out the esri/map the error goes away BUT the results are NOT displayed on the map.